# how to create setup for excel addin?

Tags: vb.net, excel, add-in, setup-project

I have a created an excel addin application in vb.net using vs2010.The application is working fine while running from IDE. Now I want to create a setup for the application to install the same addin in other system. How can I do this? I created a setup project and added the dll of the addin and created setup file. When I installed it in other machine, installation was succesful. However I could not see the addin in excel when i opened it. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot see it in Options -> Add-ins? Is it a dll or an xll add-in?

Comment: The installation was succesfull but it's not visible in Add-ins menu.it's an xll add-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of Excel Add-ins displayed in the "Available Add-Ins" dialog is rebuilt at Excel startup.
It's based on Excel built-in add-ins and 3rd party customer add-ins. The locations of the 3rd party add-ins, the ones you are interested in installing, are in two places; per user and per machine locations. The per machine location is used by all accounts on the PC, and that's located in <program files>\Microsoft Office\<Office version>\Library. The per user location is at <root drive:>\users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns.

If you install in the per-machine location, then the user would need admin rights to install there.

There is also a 3rd addin location, that is previous addins that were manually loaded and stored in the user's XLB setting file. The XLB file is a binary file and not something that an installer would touch.