# Excel Macro Addin - location for addin

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, excel-2007, vba

just wondering where to put this macro. It's supposed to cause correctly labelled excel files ato save as PDF as well whenever the user hits save. I have a similar Macro working without issue for Word, but for the life of me I can't seem to work out where this macro goes.

I'm running on Xp Sp3 with Excel 2007. I've tried saving it in a module within a .xlam to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\XLSTART`, `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\12.0`, `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Templates` etc. but no joy?

Am I missing something obvious (no surprise)?

```
Sub FileSave()
'
' FileSave Macro
'
'
  Dim StrFile As String
  Dim StrPath As String
  Dim StrName As String
  Dim StrPDFName As String

  StrPath = ActiveSheet.Path 'Get document path
  StrFile = ActiveSheet.Name 'Get document name

  If StrName <> "" Then

    MsgBox "We have a string name"

    StrName = Left(StrFile, (InStr(StrFile, ".") - 1))

      StrPDFName = StrPath + "\" + StrName + ".pdf"

      If InStr(StrFile, "_fmpro_temp") Then

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= StrPDFName, _
            Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        MsgBox StrName + " has been saved. " & vbNewLine & _
            "If you're finished, please close the file," & vbNewLine & _
            "and return to FileMaker to accept or discard this version.", _
            vbInformation, "FileMaker Pro Versioning"

      End If

  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: why about adding `debug.print strPath, strFile` before the first `If` ? That should give you a hint I guess.

Comment: I've also tried `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Startup` which is supposed to be a trusted location...

Comment: @Dycey: Is your problem sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is to be an Excel Add-in, then if you call

```
Application.UserLibraryPath()
```

That will give you the directory to save add-ins to which will be something like: C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns\

Answer (score 0):

The location of the addin should be different from where the addin tries to save the user's documents. (ie in general you don't mix programs and documents).
You typically want to store an Excel addin in one of two places; either for all users of the pc or for an individual user. The difference is, addins for individual users are typically custom or adhoc.
For the locations to store the addins, see [stackoverflow: where to store excel addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598665/how-to-create-setup-for-excel-addin/7775010#7775010)

For storing the user's PDF document, you should give the user the option of overriding the save location by using the standard open file dialog that has been primed with the user's document directory as the root.

Comment: Err, point one, well taken. Err, point two - actually no. The reason for the addin, is that it's the simplest way to get Excel to produce a pdf that can be read programmatically by another system - provided the other system knows where to look ;-) so, overring the save location is a no-no.